# Need to reset Solr home directory

Tags: linux, solr, directory, path

I am trying to start a Solr session (has worked in the past). At some point I set the Solr home directory to `/home/dpatel1/solr-8.5.2`. But, now I have solr-8.6.1. I just want reset the home directory so that it defaults to `server/solr`. I have made sure that the directory is not being set in `~/.bashrc`. I have also tried opening a new shell because I thought it was not a global path.

When I run `echo $SOLR_HOME`, I get `/home/dpatel1/solr-8.5.2`.

Here is the error I am getting when I run `bin/solr start`:

```
*** [WARN] *** Your open file limit is currently 1024.  
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption. 
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh
*** [WARN] ***  Your Max Processes Limit is currently 62865. 
 It should be set to 65000 to avoid operational disruption. 
 If you no longer wish to see this warning, set SOLR_ULIMIT_CHECKS to false in your profile or solr.in.sh

Solr home directory /home/dpatel1/solr-8.5.2 not found!
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Does Solr automatically starts if you reboot your machine or do you have to manually start it after a reboot? If it starts automatically I would suspect that the scripts that starts it probably sets SOLR_HOME.